# Multi Level Category in Select Option

Tags: php, laravel, recursion

I have a categories table :

```
| cid  | title | slug | parent_id | image |status |
```

I want to show category list in select option, But i need to add a dash character ('-') before any categories that have a parent category.

### Example as follows:

Furniture

-Table

--Sidetable

---Designer Table

---Simple Table

-Sofa

-Chair

-Doors

### Controller

```
public function edit($id)
{
    $data=Category::all();
    $item=Category::find($id);
    return view('admin.category.edit',array('item'=>$item,'data'=>$data));
}
```

### View

```
@foreach($data as $category)
<option value="{{$category->cid}}" @if($category->cid == $item->parent_id) selected="selected" @endif> {{ $category->parent_id ? ' -- ' . $category->name : $category->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

### Model

```
class Category extends Model
{
    protected 
$primaryKey = 'cid';
protected $table = 'categories';

protected $fillable = 
array('name','url','description','cover','status','parent_id');

function getRouteKeyName() {
    return 'url';
}

public function parents()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('app\Category', 'parent_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('app\Category', 'parent_id','cid');
}
```

}

Comment: so the code you wrote in the blade , is it not working. or you want different approach

Comment: this code is working for first or second level. i want to create it multilevel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this option will solve the problem (in order to simplify some mandatory checks for empty values are omitted):

### Controller:

```
public $categories = [];
public $optionsList = [];

public function edit($id)
{
    $this->categories = Category::all()->toArray();
    $item = Category::find($id);

    $firstLevelCategories = Arr::where($this->categories, function ($item, $key) {
        return empty($item['parent_id']);
    });
    $this->processCategoriesLevel($firstLevelCategories);

    return view('edit', ['item' => $item, 'data' => $this->optionsList]);
}

private function processCategoriesLevel($categories, $level = 0) {
    $level++;

    foreach ($categories as $key => $category) {
        $children = Arr::where($this->categories, function ($value, $key) use ($category) {
            return $category['cid'] == $value ['parent_id'];
        });
        $this->optionsList[] = [
            'cid' => $category['cid'],
            'name' => str_repeat('-', $level - 1) . ' ' . $category['name'],
        ];

        $this->processCategoriesLevel($children, $level);
    }
}
```

### View:

```
@foreach($data as $category)
    <option
        value="{{$category['cid']}}"
        @if($category['cid'] == $item->parent_id) selected="selected" @endif
    >
        {{$category['name']}}
    </option>
@endforeach
```

Comment: i used this, but it is showing error `Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\Arr' not found` @manzor

Comment: add `use Illuminate\Support\Arr;` to controller

Comment: hi there is order issue, childrens and parent categories not coming togeather. @manzor, pls suggest me what can i do to fix this.

Comment: can you show the category table and the final output of the options list?